# javascript function is not invoked at the first time onclick

Tags: php, javascript

I have a following code:

```
$this->content->text  .=
         '<div id="gv_block_div">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="pop('.htmlspecialchars($jsonObject).', \''.$root.'\', '.$userid.')">Click Here</a> 
         </div>';  

return $this->content;
```

When I login and click "Click Here" the onclick event doesn't trigger. It works at the second click. However, after that (before logging out), single click works just fine.

What should be the potential problem?

Comment: [HTML belongs in `.html` files, CSS belongs in `.css` files, JS belongs in `.js` files](http://zzzzbov.com/html-css-js).

Comment: He's just shakin' things up. Keeping the other devs on their toes and stuff.

Comment: Are there any messages in the JS console?

Comment: Would need to see the code for `pop()` in the javascript and probably everything else too.  Though I imagine you just need to do some debugging, look at error messages from the console.

Comment: :/, I am wondering whats happening. The error is not showing up now. What I am seeing now is, when I log in, there pops up a message remember password? if I dont do anything on this, I need to click 2 times. Also, I changed the console options of firebug, is it anything to do with that??..:/

Comment: What error isn't showing up now? Your question didn't mention an error. Since the problem is happening on the client, it would be helpful if you showed the resulting HTML, rather than the PHP that generates it.

Comment: Sorry, replace error with behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try 
`<a href="#" onclick="return pop('.htmlspecialchars($jsonObject).', \''.$root.'\', '.$userid.')">Click Here</a>`
and then , return false; in the pop() function , or wrap it in an other function that returns false. that might do the trick.